# Macro for Visual Studio version

Tags: visual-c++-2008, visual-c++-2010

I am using the command line to automate a few things in my project. I am using a lot of macros, for example `$(PlatformName) - gives me Win32 or Win64`, which help me write commands for all configuration types. I am wondering if there is a similar macro that I can use for the current version of Visual Studio, for example one that will return `VS2008` or `VS2010`.

Comment: Wow, I am really surprised that it is so difficult to find a list of all the environment variables in Visual Studio. This is rather disappointing.. I thought for sure there would be an MSDN article that lists all of them. I'll keep looking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like it. [Here is a list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) of available macros. That's no guarantee there aren't other ways to detect the VC version in use, however; one option might be to work it out from the VCinstalldir by exploring subdirectories. Like any buildsystem activity this rapidly becomes a lot of special cases etc...

Comment: Thank you for that link! It was driving me nuts!

Comment: Thanks for the link, I could not find it, kept going to the wrong macros page

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about VS2008 explicitly but VS2010 and VS2012 offer $(VisualStudioVersion) with values of 10.0 and 11.0 respectively.